# IsoDateTimeConverter not deserializing hours from 1-24h

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a date in the following format:

```
"22/07/2016 17:50:50"
```

And I'm using JSON.NET:

```
new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" };
```

The deserialization works well. However if it is overnight the dates comes back in the following format:

```
"22/07/2016 1:50:50"
```

Then the deserialization throws an exception unless I change the DateTimeFormat to "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss". However I don't think that won't work when I have a 2-digit-hour coming through.

Is there any way of specifying from 1-2 digits in 24h format in the ISO converter?

Comment: HH hour format requires two digits.  Instead just use one H.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't sure H would work for hours with two digits (10-23). Cheers